# Laravel Namespace is not created

Tags: laravel, namespaces

my composer.json include:

```
 "psr-4": { 
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Laracasts\\": "app/Laracasts/"
    }
```

But autoload-prs4.php in vendor/composer have no code like this

```
'Laracasts\\' => array($baseDir . '/app/Laracasts'),
```

So I can not use my new namespace.

Please give me your help!

Comment: Did you updated your composer after setting this values within your `composer.json`. Then you can check that `autoload_psr4.php` must contains `'App\\' => array($baseDir . '/app'),`

Comment: I updated. autoload_prs4 has this line 'App\\' => array($baseDir . '/app'), but the other hasn't

Comment: Did you updated your composer.json file

Answer (score 0):

If You add a new directory 'Laracasts',you need to update composer and add a file "Laracasts" in config directory ,then add this ::

```
return [
'modules'=>array(
    "Laracasts",

),
```

];

Comment: Sorry, Can I ask. In lavarel 5. Where did you store new namespace. In /app or /app/controller. Please teach me!

Answer (score 0):

You can add namespace in your controller at first like this:

Controller::

```
namespace App\Modules\Inventory\Controllers;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BuyerController extends Controller
{

}
```